# How would I incorporate a bootstrap css stylesheet into my express/node js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

So at the moment, the approach I am taking is I'm using this code to retrieve my html file.

```
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public_html/index.html");
})
```

The html file is a form with method="post" and a button to submit the form. I have imported the relevant css code here.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Back on the js side I have use this code to collect the values from the html form when it is submitted.

```
app.post("/survey", function (request, response, next) {
let firstname = request.body.fname;
let surname = request.body.sname;
etc...
```

Then here is the part where I'm not sure whether or not I'm taking the wrong approach or not.

I use some response.write() methods to display the form results.

```
response.write('<h1>SURVEY REPORT</h1>');
response.write('<dl><dd><strong>Firstname entered: </strong>' + firstname + '</dd>');
response.write('<dd><strong>Surname entered: </strong>' + surname + '</dd>');
etc...
```

While this does kind of work, it doesn't seem to implement the css stylesheet at all. How would I get the css stylesheet to work with the output?

I have also tried creating a sql database in memory via sqlite3 and store the values there, but now I'm stuck with how I would use that table to output into an html format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a better way to do
You can you [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) or ejs.

Add this line on app.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Then you can response to the request by :-

```
res.render('/filepath/index.hbs', {write variables for the file as json})
```